# Multiple array error when using str_replace

Tags: php, laravel, str-replace

I want to replace a text as below.

```
$text = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre><code>[[EXAMPLE]] this is a text. <br />[[EXAMPLE2]]</code></pre>
<p style="text-align: center;"><br /><br /></p>
</body>
</html>';


$products['type'] = 1;
$products['quantity'] = 2300.0;
$products['grade'] = null;

 $searchVal = array(
'[[EXAMPLE]]'
'[[EXAMPLE2]]'
);

 $replaceVal = array(
'replace word',
 $products
); 

$text = str_replace($searchVal, $replaceVal, $text);
```

I did not run this code. This fail is "Array to string conversion"

How can i do this.

Comment: Please tag Programming language used.

Comment: The message is clear: You can't use an array as a string, maybe you only need an element from that array, something like: $products['name']

Comment: I want to use multiple. Because I'm going to parse [[EXAMPLE2]] on the html page. I guess it doesn't work the way I want. Do I have to use a single?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value
>   from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject

Make sure both `$searchVal` and `$replaceVal` are linear arrays, currently they are not.

Your `$searchVal` definition lacks a comma.

Your `$replaceVal` is an array where the second element is another array.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you!